# Getting left and right bounds from df.query() string

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to get some extra info from strings that I feed into [df.query()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html)

Currently I'm doing data cleaning with:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': range(1, 6),
                   'B': range(10, 0, -2),
                   'C': range(10, 5, -1)})

query_string = "6 <= B <= 8"

df.query(query_string)

df >>
   A   B    C
1  2   8    9
2  3   6    8
```

I'm wondering if it would be possible to somehow get the bounds for the query, something like this:

```
query_string = "6 <= B <= 8"
bounds = some_get_bounds_function(query_string)

bounds >>
(6, 8)
```

Tried looking around for any ideas better than just parsing the strings myself.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can `split` and return the part of the string before the first and after the last space and create a `tuple` by separating the two with a comma and enclosing with parentheses:

```
bounds = (int(query_string.split()[0]), int(query_string.split()[-1]))
bounds
(6, 8)
```

Or better, per your comment:

```
bounds = (df['B'].min(), df['B'].max())
bounds
(6, 8)
```

Comment: @user219574 kindly hit the checkmark next to my answer if I have solved. Thank you!

Comment: Ah, I was hoping to find something that was not just manual string parsing but I'm probably going to use your solution to just get it done!

My worry is cases like: "8 >= B >= 6" or "B >= 6" which are valid query strings but are annoying cases for manual string parsing!

Comment: @user219574 just tagging you here to see my updated answer in case you didn't see update.